# Default link script in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I have this very simple makefile:

```
P = hello_world.exe
OBJECTS = main.o
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O3
LDLIBS = 
CC = clang

$(P): $(OBJECTS)
```

When I run make it will compile main.c but it will not link to hello_world.exe. Shouldn't that be happening automatically?

My environment is cygwin 64bit.

The output of make -p is here: http://pastebin.com/qbr0sRXL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default rule for `.exe` files that I'm aware of (or can find in that output).

You'll need to write one yourself.

If your output was `hello_world` **and** you had a `hello_world.c`/`hello_world.cpp` source file and *also* a `main.c`/`main.cpp` file then your makefile as written would work I believe (since the default `%: %.o` rule would apply and your added prerequisite would be added to the `hello_world` prerequisite list).

Comment: I renamed my main.c to hello_world.c and I changed the target to hello_world. Then it works.